# change the internal HDD to be an external USB HDD

Tags: drivers

I have a HDD in the laptop with ubuntu installed. 
Now I want to take this HDD out and put in the USB cradle. But I can make it bootup as a USB HDD. 
Can any one help please ?

Comment: Is this a UEFI machine?  Can it boot off USB?  Have you ever run update-grub or upgraded kernels?

Comment: Sorry it can NOT boot up.  I want to boot up and use as an external USB HDD. Sorry I do not understand what is UEFI meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Some older machines cannot boot off a USB device.  If in the BIOS boot order you have a USB choice, then you can boot off USB.  If you don't, then you need to boot some other way, and then run the programs on the USB device.

Assuming you can boot off USB, the USB device will probably be given a different name than the internal hard disk(sda).  If you have ever run update-grub or installed an updated kernel, then any actual devices mentioned in the grub.cfg file will have been converted to a UUID reference, which is device independent -- you should just be able to move the disk anywhere and even if the device name changes, the UUID will not, so it should still boot.

The new machines with Windows 8 preinstalled, have a new boot mechanism, and are called UEFI machines.  The legacy boot mechanism starts with code sitting in the first block of the disk, while the UEFI boot runs bootloaders from a FAT filesystem.  The internal hard disk would have a bootloader order (in case of several bootloaders) to run from the filesystem.  If you move the disk to an external enclosure, then the internal order may not be valid, so the default bootloader for "removable media" would be used (/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi).  That default bootloader may or may not have been set up by your installer, since it typically is not used for an internal disk, but it can be just a copy (renamed to bootx64.efi) of the bootloader typically run.  Anyway, UEFI may not apply here.

It's usually pretty easy to just move an internal disk to an external enclosure.